# Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects

Tags: build, azure-devops

I have set up a build definition on VSTS. It builds fine on my local machine. But I get the following error when I start the build process

> [error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\My.Project\My.Project.csproj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the project name in the error carefully. Chances are its not actually in your solution `.sln` ... and wouldn't build if it were. By default, VSTS will try to build all `.csproj` files regardless whether they are in your solution or not. Remove all `.csproj` files for projects you don't want to be built.

In my case. I deleted the `\My.Project` directory (which contained the `.csproj` file) and the build suceeded.

Comment: thanks, somehow we had a 2nd csproj file in the directory

Answer (score 0):

edit your.csproj and add MvcRazorCompileOnPublish as false

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

views will be included in publish without the VSTS build failure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my project had the line `<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>` in the csproj file, which caused the Pipeline job to fail in DevOps when it tried to create a package.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with my automation code's Build pipeline with CI. I was using ".Net Core" task for test execution.

**Solution**:

1. I switched my "test" execution task from .Net Core to "Visual Studio test".
2. In VSTest task under "Test files" i specified exact project name which contains Test Cases. Instead of main solution.dll. As shown in image.

[image]